# How can I store results from MySQL to PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I tried storing data to php array from mysql using under code. But it's not working. 
This code:

```
echo $answerArray[count][i];
```

shows the correct result. But this code:

```
echo $answerArray[0][0];
```

doesn´t show anything.

What should I do to fix it?
Thank you.

Full code:

```
   $count = 0; //answer count
   $answerArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFromR, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { //add array from db
     for($i = 0; $i < $questionNumber; $i++) {
     $j = $i + 1;
     $answerArray[count][i] = $row["num$j"];
     echo $answerArray[count][i]; //is working.
     }
$count++;
}
echo '<br />';
echo $answerArray[0][0]; //something wrong!!! I cannot get anything from this.
```

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($answerArray);` ?

Comment: `$answerArray[count][i]` ?? Should be `$answerArray[$count][$i]` for a starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will work

```
 $answerArray[$count][$i] = $row["num$j"];
```

(add $ before count and i)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but shouldn't the [i] be [$i]?

Comment: yes, I think about this too. But he/she says that `[i]` is working. And it cannot work. AFAIK.

Comment: I believe that if your error reporting is set to none, `$array[i]` is equal to `$array['i']` so, this is why it works when `echo $array[i]` afterwards. But `echo $array[0]` will not, even if `$i = 0`, and all that without a single warning

Comment: `$foo[i]` is equivalent to `$foo['i']` if i is not a defined constant, so _reading_ `$answerArray[count][i]` should work, I assume that is what he means by working and `[0][0]` not working